# what does a eth_call mean without to field?

Tags: evm, json-rpc

I'm using openzepplin tests, one of them sends an `eth_call` RPC call but without a `to` field although [the doc](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_call) says that is not optional. What does it mean? Does it mean that `to = from`?

Comment: Can you share the test code?  My guess is that it is an error omitting `to`.